# Google Chart not loaded when asp.net application is deployed in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

The Google Chart (Timeline) is not loading whenever the project is deployed in IIS. Otherwise, when I am running the same from VS2010, its working fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the server it is not working on it possibly blocking access to the libraries needed by Google Maps?  Maybe a proxy setting on the machine.  We had a similar issue.  My local machine was open to access information from outside our network, but the server (since it was an intranet site) was blocked from talking outside, so Google maps would work on my machine but not on the server.  I ended up using highcharts.js instead.

Comment: Well, I have checked that outside urls can be accessed from the server hosted project. I hope that's what you mentioned about talking to the outside network from server. I'll give it a try with highcharts.